# hide woocommerce tab if empty

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm doing a post query in a tab and I want the tab to not show up if no posts are found. So far I can get custom text to show up if there are no posts, but when I try to code it to not show the tab then it doesn't show the tab even if there are posts.

```
function en_in_tab_content() {

// The new tab content
global $product;
$story = get_the_title();

$args = array('post_type'=>array('product'), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC','meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'en_anthology_stories',
                'value' => $story,
                'compare' => 'like',
                )
            )
        );
       query_posts($args);
        //the loop start here
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :{?>
                    <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>" style="float: left; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;" width="129" height="200"/>
                    </a>
                    <?php } else : { ?>
                    <img src="http://enspirepublishing.com/forbiddenfiction/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/10/ForbiddenFic_CvrPlaceholderSM.png" style="float: left; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;"/>
                    <?php }
                    endif; ?>

            <b><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title();?></a></b><br><br>
            <?php the_content();?>
       <?php endwhile; else:?>
 <style>li.en_in_tab_tab { display:none !important; }</style>


 <?php endif;

 }
```

So that makes it not show up at all even if there are posts.
I've also tried using

```
 unset ($tabs['en_in_tab']);
```

but no luck there either.

Comment: and the style tag shows up in the html even if there are posts?

Comment: @inarilo yes, the style tag shows

Comment: does the function run more than once?

Comment: @inarilo As far as I can tell, no. But I'm not sure how to check for that.

Comment: are there posts for multiple values of $story?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... 
but for en_anthology_stories either multiple posts are selected or none at all 
and multiple posts should be able to show up as a result of this query
though $story = get_the_title(); should refer only  to the current post

Comment: i can't find anything wrong with the logic, so if posts are found it should work, the only way then is that posts are not found, which would indicate a problem with your query. it could also be because of query_posts, it's best not used as it can cause unexpected problems: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I followed your link and noticed that I hadn't included wp_reset_query(); after the endif; and that seems to have fixed the issue.